# Result object does not return rows when querying SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

The code:

```
engine = db.engine
conn = engine.connect()
query = open('sql_file.sql', 'r')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.read(), conn)
```

returns the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

And my query in the sql file runs perfectly fine in SSMS and returns a large table that I want to read with Pandas. Why does it not return any rows and how I can execute the sql file in a way so the data goes into a dataframe?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] (include the query in the question).

Answer (score 3):

You may find that your  `.sql` file is generating multiple result sets or includes statements that generate messages which are being interpreted by sqlalchemy as result sets. For example, creating a temp table will include a message about how many rows were inserted. SSMS will display these on a tab behind any result sets, but sqlalchemy won't make any assumptions about what to do with them.

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` or `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` to the top of your query file. This should limit the messages that come back. Also check if your query includes a `USE` statement, and try removing it. The default DB can be set on the connection string instead.

Lastly, you can try getting the cursor from sqlalchemy and moving the cursor to the required result set using `cursor.nextset()`. The result you get back is a list of tuples which you can then use `DataFrame.from_records()` to build your dataframe.

```
raw_connection = db_engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = raw_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.nextset()

    column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    rows = cursor.fetchall() # List of tuples
    
    cursor.close()
finally:
    raw_connection.close()

# Use from_records for a list of tuples
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data=rows, columns=column_names, index=None)
```

See:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets
and:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

Comment: The use of `USE` was my problem. Why isn't it allowed? It makes no sense that `USE` returns a result set...